# puppet execute problem after file creation

Tags: puppet, execute

I don't know to solve this problem.
I want to run postmap command after creation or change of a file.

```
        ensure => 'present',
        value  => 'hash:${postfix_path}${virtual_alias_maps}',
        #notify => Exec['generate ${postfix_path}${virtual_alias_maps}']   }

      file {"${name}":
        ensure  => $ensure,
        require => [File[$name], Exec["generate ${name}"]],   }

      exec { 'generate ${name}':
        command     => 'postmap ${name}',
        path        => $::path,
        subscribe   => File[$name],
        refreshonly => true   
     }
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

Single-quoted strings are not subject to variable interpolation.  Use double-quoted strings instead if you want interpolation, like this:

```
  exec { "generate ${name}":
    command     => "postmap ${name}",
    path        => $::path,
    subscribe   => File[$name],
    refreshonly => true   
 }
```

That also assumes that variable `$::path` actually contains a path suitable for locating the `postmap` executable.  That's conceivable, but I'm inclined to doubt that it is actually the case for you.  Is there so much uncertainty about where that executable is installed (and where any external programs it executes are installed) that you cannot provide a literal path that will suffice?

Additionally, there are separate issues with the `file` declaration presented:

> ```
>       file {"${name}":
>         ensure  => $ensure,
>         require => [File[$name], Exec["generate ${name}"]],   }
> ```

- the declared `File` resource expresses a dependency on itself.  This creates a dependency loop that will cause catalog building to fail.
- the declared `File` resource expresses a dependency on `Exec["generate ${name}"]`, which resource also expresses a dependency on it (`subscribe` has this among its effects).  This constitutes another, separate dependency loop that will cause catalog building to fail.  Between this and the previous, you probably just want to drop the `require` attribute altogether.
- you are ensuring the file to a state indicated by variable `$ensure`.  Although that is not inherently wrong, you need to be sure that the effects are correct for all cases.  In particular, if you ensure the file `absent` then it is probably incorrect for the `Exec` to be triggered when the file is brouught into that state.  If it is possible to ensure the file to be a `directory` then that, too, probably would not play nicely with the effect of the `Exec`.

Also, you are not directly managing the content of the file, its ownership, or its mode.  That may be ok, and maybe even desirable, but I recommend considering whether it would be feasible to put Puppet in full control of the file.